# Unable to run facebook SDK code ?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I am really new in this Facebook application making stuff and really interested in making some things. Though I am a beginner in this coding stuff... So, I need a little help

SO, this is the code.

```
<?php

require_once("app/src/facebook.php");

  $config = array(
      'appId' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
      'secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
      'fileUpload' => false, // optional
      'allowSignedRequest' => false, // optional, but should be set to false for non-canvas apps
  );
  $facebook = new Facebook($config);

$user = $facebook->getUser();    ?>

Hello <fb:name uid='<?php echo $user; ?>' useyou='false' possessive='true' />!
```

When I run this code, it should have showed me the name of the user of the ID... but it does not work(Returns 0), what is wrong with this code?

Comment: try `var_dump($user)`. I'm not familiar with FB php SDK but I guess you get an array, or an object, with user data. `It does not work` isn't very helpful as a debug message

Comment: You are not logging the user in. This code will never work.

Comment: How can I login a user? any help please? @JimmyKane

Comment: Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20799393/facebook-sdk-php-example-not-working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the rest of [Facebook's code example](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/profilewithgraphapi/), especially the part where it's testing the `$user_id` variable and, if empty, provide a login link.

```
if($user_id) {
  # [...]
} else {

  // No user, print a link for the user to login
  $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
  echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced this issue on different occasions but SDK issue is not happening to everyone. So I'm not sure what goes wrong here. But I dig in to it little bit and found solution as mentioned below.

**SOLUTION : This worked for me after trying for many solutions for this issue.**

In base_facebook.php file, find the makeRequest() method and check for following Line.

```
$opts = self::$CURL_OPTS;
```

Immediately following it, add this line

```
$opts[CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER] = false;
```

More details can be found here - http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-authenticate-your-users-with-facebook-connect/